# Filling an array using a pointer

Tags: c++

Trying to fill an array using a pointer so each index of array contains its' index. The output I am currently getting is this +DD;D;DD. Could someone explain where I am going wrong on this? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    int NUMBER_ELEMENTS;
    cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
    cin >> NUMBER_ELEMENTS;
    short array1[NUMBER_ELEMENTS];
    short *arrPtr;
    arrPtr = array1; 
    short i = 0;
    while(i < NUMBER_ELEMENTS)
    {
        *arrPtr = i;
        arrPtr = arrPtr + 1;
        cout << "+" + array1[i];
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't use a variable to declare array size; you need a constant value.

Comment: Undefined behavior. Adding a `short` to a literal string, "+" doesn't do what you think it does. Another thing you did wrong is use variable length arrays, which is not standard C++.

Comment: Ah yes, I removed the string from the print statement and the indices are now being printed. Can you explain how this is a variable length array? I am gathering length from user to define array but not changing the length after.

Comment: What is the constant value of `NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS`? It is not a constant value, therefore the size of the array varies at runtime. The first time you run this program, it might have five values. The next time you run thig program, it might have eight values. That's what a "variable length array" is. This is not standard C++.

Comment: `short array1[NUMBER_ELEMENTS];` As @SamVarshavchik noted VLAs are not supported by the C++ standard. They are provided by g++ as an extension to the language. Your compiler should be warning your about that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: The length of an automatic array can not be given at runtime. It must be known at compile time. In order to create an array with dynamic length, you can use `std::vector` instead.

> explain how this is a variable length array?

You can input different values in different executions of the program. Therefore the length varies. Even the value staying the same is by itself not sufficient. The expression used the array length must be a compile time constant expression.

---

Problem 2: `"+" + array1[i]` doesn't do what you probably think it does.

The string literal is an array of characters. `array1[i]` is an integer. When you add an integer to an array using the plus-operator, the array decays to a pointer to first element of the array, and the the pointer is incremented by number given as the operand.

Therefore `"+" + 0` increments the pointer by zero places, so the string printed in the first iteration is `"+"`. `"+" + 1` increments the pointer by one places. After the + character, there is only the null terminator, so the printed string is empty. After that iteration, the later iterations overflow the array, and the behaviour of the program is undefined.